# pointer object using default assignment operator

Tags: c++

Suppose an object has a pointer type as its data member.

1. What happen when we assign that object using default assignment operator?
2. What happen if we use delete one object in the above mentioned situation?

Comment: The default copy-ctor / op= does member-wise copy. A pointer is a simple basic data-type, it just gets copied. The default dtor calls the dtor of all members, base-class or member. For non-class-types, that does nothing.

Comment: 2) If your object O's destructor does `delete m_pointer` and you don't write a deep-copying copy constructor, then all remaining copies of an O will contain wild pointers after any is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

1. The pointer is copy assigned, as you expect (the default behavior is to memberwise copy/move assign everything)
2. Then you might have a memory leak if your class owns the pointee and your destructor does not `delete` the pointer. Using smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr<>` helps a lot to avoid such situations.

Comment: having a pointer data type doesn't mean that the pointed object was allocated with `new`, or that it is owned by the wrapping object

Comment: @pqnet, this is why I use "if`s", tell me if its unclear

Comment: legit, the question is unclear. A lot of things "happens" when you delete an object...

Answer (score 0):

1. The pointer is copied
2. Nothing. The object is deleted and the other object is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pointer is simply copied without touching the pointee at all
2. Pointee is not affected, its memory is not freed *edit:* Unless of course the destructor does about it...

I'm pretty sure you're looking for a shared smart pointer, such as [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Answer (score 0):

1. What happen when we assign that object using default assignment operator?

   - The assignment operator performs a member-wise assignment of every data member of the class for which it is defined. That means if there is some pointer *`p`* in class *`X`*, the assignment operator will simply *assign* it to the pointer from that other object. For example:

     ```
     X& X::operator=(const X& rhs) { // default-assignment operator
         this->p = rhs.p;
         return *this;
     }
     ```

     Watch out, because the above might cause a memory leak if `p` was previously allocated with memory that was not deallocated before the assignment. If you're using a pointer, you might want to wrap it in a [`std::unique_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) which will safely delete the memory. Otherwise it will be lost after the assignment.

     Moreover, the above performs a *shallow* copy of the pointer. If you want a deep copy, you may need to override this method and do it manually (or wrap the pointer in a class which does it internally).
2. What happen if we use delete one object in the above mentioned situation?

   - If you `delete` the contained pointer, but never assign it to the other object, your class will still be in a valid state, but the value of your pointer will be indeterminate. If you ever use the pointer as if it had a value thereafter, you will invoke [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) on your program.

     It may be better to give your pointer a value of `nullptr` after its deletion, that way you can at least know that it doesn't point to a valid object (don't worry about this while using `std::unique_ptr/std::shared_ptr`. Also, if it makes sense semantically for your pointer to be copy-assigned from the other object, you should do so.